# Where are the really high quality and complex Swing components?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

Looking at Swing, I have the feeling that it comes with many useful and reasonable atomic components in its core. And when I look at the Web there are hundrets of quickly plugged together components (among them many date/time pickers, pimped lists and tables), which have in common that I could easily write them on my own, if I needed them.

When I build big software and come to the point where I need a domain-specific component which is really big, I mostly come to the point where I have to write it on my own, which, due to the point that they are not just plugged together lists and tables, isn't done qickly.

**So, the question is, why are there no Swing component galleries which contain more than just customized date/time pickers or lists with added tree support.** Where are the components which really raise the level of abstraction, or are in best case domain-specific?

Comment: The problem with complex components is that they are difficult to reuse.

Comment: give an example of such a component in another framework, such as MFC.

Answer (score 3):

At http://www.jidesoft.com/ you can find very complex components such as Pivot Grid, Code Editor, Gantt Chart etc.

As far as domain specific components go, Mark Byers is correct - they are difficult to resuse and very hard to sell :)

Answer (score 1):

True, it would be nice with a site that has a gallery of complex Swing components.

I like the [MiG Calendar](http://www.migcalendar.com/) component. Also the [Cezanne](http://www.centigrade.de/en/products/cezanne-look-and-feel-engine) LookAndFeel looks really professional.

Comment: Thank you for the link to Cezanne L&F, didn't know that one yet.

Answer (score 1):

swingx has some useful components, like combo-boxes with autocompletion, text field with prompt built in, hyperlinks, etc, many things that *should* be standard!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is that most complex and nice Swing components are developed internally and not for sale. Most companies won't hesitate to mix their widgets code with their very specific libraries too, which makes it tough to reuse in other projects(tight coupling).